# How to create an android project using Kotlin DSL and buildSrc

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have searched a lot and I can only find guides or results that tell you how to migrate an existing Android project that uses the normal groovy layout that is default into a project with Kotlin DSL and buildSrc. I was wondering if there is a way to create an android project that was rather than having to migrate it.

The only thing I can think of is someone creating a github action for you to fork, but I would rather be able to create one from Android Studio itself.

Comment: How’s this not a thing yet?

Comment: @flopshot Yeah I'm not sure either. It's clear that Google is recommending to use Kotlin instead of Groovy for Gradle scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Using the terminal in Android Studio, navigate to a new folder (this is where the project will be saved) and type the following:

```
gradle init --type kotlin-application
```

Press [CTRL + ENTER] to have Android Studio process the command. The run tab at the bottom should open and will ask which DSL you would like to use for the project. Click the area after this text and enter 2 for Kotlin. Then enter your project name and package name.

I would still recommend using the standard GUI interface within Android Studio to create a project and manually convert the files, as the method above does not create all the standard files that Android Studio does. In other words, you will likely find it more time consuming using the Build Init Plugin.

reference: [Build Init Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html)